# When does the integral of $f(z)$ vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given some theorems in complex analysis I understand that given a convex domain and the homotopy of the closed curves in that domain in which $f(z)$ is defined, then the integral $f(z)$ over such a curve will vanish.

Given only a connected by arc domain or in other words a punctured disk such that the ( simple ) closed path is in the open domain itself but encloses the point in which the function has a singularity, in what circumstances concerning the singularities and $f(z)$ would the integral of $f(z)$ over such a curve vanish ( simple pole, poles of order $>1$, removable singularities... ?

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: do you know about the residue theorem ?

Comment: If one has exactly one singularity, then the integral vanishes if and only if this is a removable singularity. But if you have more than one singularity, then everything is possible. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3p_E9jZOU8 .

Comment: @Crostul What you're saying is incorrect. Take $1/z^2$ around $0$.

Comment: We have $$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$$ for _all_ closed (sufficiently regular) curves in the domain if and only if $f$ has a primitive on the domain. Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: I already answered a very similar question asked by the same person. I'm not sure if posting the question again is the appropriate thing to do.